# How can I exit fullscreen when watching flash videos

Tags: flash

I find that when watching a flash video in full screen, if I press ESC key to exit the full screen mode, my screen turns grey and I cannot do anything.

Ubuntu keeps running as I can still adjust the volume with the keyboard shortcut. I tried going to text mode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fx</kbd>) and kill chrome but that didn't work.

In fact I don't know what I have to kill or disable to get the desktop back. The only solution I find is restarting lightdm which is not fun if I had some unsaved work.

This happens on Chrome. The plugin is

> Shockwave Flash 11.6 r602
>   Name:  Shockwave Flash
>   Description:   Shockwave Flash 11.6 r602
>   Version:   11.6.602.167
>   Location: /opt/google/chrome/PepperFlash/libpepflashplayer.so

Comment: I don't understand :( First there's mention of jwplayer and later there's mention of Chrome. What is the connection?

Comment: nevermind, I have this problem for youtube like videos